# autocmd event for MenuPopup in Vim

Tags: events, vim, menu, autocmd

### Objective

Map <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> to `<up>` and `<down>` during `ins-completion`, like so:

```
autocmd MenuPopup inoremap k <down>
autocmd MenuPopup inoremap j <up>
```

And undo the temporary mapping when the `MenuPopup` is gone:

```
autocmd MenuPopupGone iunmap k
autocmd MenuPopupGone iunmap j
```

### Question

What is the correct `autocmd` event for `MenuPopupGone`? As far as I know from `:help event`, there is no such event for `MenuPopupGone`.

Answer (score 2):

The `MenuPopup` event is not for the insert-mode completion menu, but for the menu that comes up with a right mouse button click.

To change mappings when the completion menu is visible, use `<expr>` mappings that evaluate `pumvisible()`:

```
:inoremap <expr> j pumvisible() ? '<Down>' : 'j'
:inoremap <expr> k pumvisible() ? '<Up>' : 'k'
```